# Why do people use cmd.exe with Process.Start so much?

Tags: discussion, canonical

A lot of questions in .NET when I see people use `Process.Start` or `ProcessStartInfo` I frequently see them launching `cmd.exe /C TheirRealProgram.exe`.

Does anyone know why people constantly do that instead of just launching `TheirRealProgram.exe` directly?

Is that "canonical example" that people get from google found here on Stack Overflow?

Does a canonical **correct** duplicate target that we can use in closing this ill-advised questions exists? If not, can we create one please.

Comment: Should be noted that it's off-topic for the main SO site too...in it's present form.

Comment: I've edited this so we can start for a canonical search or create one if none exist.

Comment: Getting I/O redirection right is rocket science and everybody gets it wrong.  Having cmd.exe take care of it is rather wise, I always recommend it.  Something like that.

Answer (score -3):

See [capture process stdout and stderr in the correct ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529662/capture-process-stdout-and-stderr-in-the-correct-ordering).

.NET doesn't have functionality to capture stdout+stderr which is quite a common task. This is basically a crutch.